# SWI-Prolog: How to use my own predicate as a condition in when/2

Tags: prolog, prolog-coroutining

I am trying to implement a Prolog program that can interact with java. To do this I use JPL as the Prolog/Java interface.

I am looking for a mechanism that allows me to execute actions automatically when the conditions become true.

The conditions are also represented by predicates. I have tried to use the predefined predicate "when/2", the problem is that as specified in the documentation [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/when.pl?public_only=false), the condition must be one of these:

- `nonvar(X)`
- `ground(X)`
- `?=(X, Y)`
- `(Cond1, Cond2)`
- `(Cond2; Cond2)`

The last two conditions seem the ones I should use, but I could not make them work.

What do I need to change to make make my own conditions ?

Please, consider `J` as a local Prolog variable here.

```
:- use_module(library(jpl)).
:- use_module(library(when)).


should_engage(J) :-
  jpl_get(J, 'shouldEngage', V),
  V==true,
  jpl_get(J, 'players', P),
  jpl_call(P, 'canSeeEnemies', [], R),
  R==true,
  jpl_get(J, 'weaponry', W),
  jpl_call(W, 'hasLoadedWeapon', [], R),
  R==true.


call_java(J) :-
  jpl_call(J, 'stateEngage', [], R).


when(should_engage(X), call_java(X)).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When/1 is part of the coroutining infrastructure that triggers actions on variable instantiation.  It uses *attributed variables* in the background.  So, if your `J`
is normally a variable that can get bound at some time you can do

```
   ...,
   when(nonvar(X), propagate(X)).

propagate(X) :-
    should_engage(X),
    call_java(X).
```

Or

```
propagate(X) :-
    (   should_engage(X)
    ->  call_java(X)
    ;   true
    ).
```

The first version will cause the instantiation of `X` to fail if `should_engage/1` fails.  The latter version not.

If it is not the binding of a variable that may make `should_engage/1` true you'll need to find some other trigger or possibly have a thread that monitors the environment at intervals and propagates.

Note that calling non-logical constructs from when/1 typically makes little sense because Prolog's computation may backtrack, unbinding `X` and rebinding it again to the same or a different value and thus your propagation may be called many times with
different or the same value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what i'm looking for !
In fact, the routine will be called by a java loop, and if i inject "J" each time without saving it in local i think that i will garatie that there will not be backtracking. The second solution worked well for me, but it will be awesome if i find a way that allows me to not inject J in every call!